# Recursive array of property values in array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

What I need is an array of property values, recursively collected from an array of objects, this is what I mean:

```
const regions = [{
  name: 'Europe',
  subRegions: [{
    name: 'BeNeLux',
    territories: [{
      code: 'NL',
      name: 'Netherlands'
    }, {
      code: 'DE',
      name: 'Germany'
    }, {
      code: 'LU',
      name: 'Luxembourgh'
    }]
  }],
  territories: [{
    code: 'UK',
    name: 'United Kingdom'
  }, {
    code: 'AL',
    name: 'Albania'
  }, {
    code: 'ZW',
    name: 'Switzerland'
  }]
}]
```

I want to get an array of all the country codes in the `regions` array.

So like:

```
const expectedOutput = ['NL', 'DE', 'LU', 'AL', 'ZW', 'UK'];
```

This what I have tried, which partly works but it's not collecting it correctly (I'm also very curious for exploring different / functional setups to solve this problem)

```
const getAllTerritoryCodesFromRegions = regions => {
  return regions
    .reduce(function r (output, region) {
      if (region?.subRegions?.length) {
        output.subRegions = region.subRegions.reduce(r, output)
      }

      if (region?.territories?.length) {
        output = [
          ...output,
          ...region.territories.map(t => t.code)
        ]
      }

      return output
    }, [])
}
```

Comment: The upper array has the country codes as the `code` property, the lower array has some country codes in the `name` property? Is that a typo?

Comment: @CertainPerformance yep was typo indeed, sorry about that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the `code` properties should always contain the country codes:

It would probably be easier to create *one* array on the first call, which gets recursively passed down as a parameter, than to create an array for every call and try to combine it later. Then you just need to `forEach` over the regions and territories and push the code to that array:

```js
const regions = [{
  name: 'Europe',
  subRegions: [{
    name: 'BeNeLux',
    territories: [{
      code: 'NL',
      name: 'Netherlands'
    }, {
      code: 'DE',
      name: 'Germany'
    }, {
      code: 'LU',
      name: 'Luxembourgh'
    }]
  }],
  territories: [{
    name: 'United Kingdom',
    code: 'UK'
  }, {
    code: 'AL',
    name: 'Albania'
  }, {
    code: 'ZW',
    name: 'Switzerland'
  }]
}];

const getAllTerritoryCodesFromRegions = (regions, allCodes=[]) => {
  regions.forEach(({ territories, subRegions }) => {
    if (territories) {
      territories.forEach(({ code }) => {
        allCodes.push(code);
      });
    }
    if (subRegions) {
      getAllTerritoryCodesFromRegions(subRegions, allCodes);
    }
  });
  return allCodes;
};
console.log(
  getAllTerritoryCodesFromRegions(regions)
);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could reduce the array by looking for arrays and return the codes.

```js
function getCodes(array) {
    return array.reduce((r, o) => {
        if ('code' in o) {
            r.push(o.code);
            return r;
        }
        Object.values(o).forEach(v => {
            if (Array.isArray(v)) r.push(...getCodes(v));
        });
        return r;
    }, []);
}

const
    regions = [{ name: 'Europe', subRegions: [{ name: 'BeNeLux', territories: [{ code: 'NL', name: 'Netherlands' }, { code: 'DE', name: 'Germany' }, { code: 'LU', name: 'Luxembourgh' }] }], territories: [{ name: 'United Kingdom', code: 'UK' }, { name: 'AL', code: 'Albania' }, { name: 'ZW', code: 'Switzerland' }] }],
    codes = getCodes(regions);

console.log(codes);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with a recursive method

```
const getAllTerritoryCodesFromRegions = array => {
    const output = [];

    array.forEach(item => {
        for (const key in item) {
            if (key === 'code') {
                output.push(item[key]);
            } else if (item.hasOwnProperty(key) && Array.isArray(item[key])) {
                const childOutput = getAllTerritoryCodesFromRegions(item[key]);
                output.push(...childOutput);
            }
        }
    });

    return output;
}
```

You can find a working example here [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wp2tho5u/). However in the dataset from your example you messed up some names and codes.