# Get all values from array of objects into array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, mapping

I have an array of objects that looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": "5eece32be3a4f43ca8e98688",
        "title": "Main",
        "children": [
            {
                "id": "5eece339e3a4f43ca8e98689",
                "title": "Child"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "5eece354e3a4f43ca8e9868a",
        "title": "Another",
        "children": [
            {
                "id": "5eece362e3a4f43ca8e9868b",
                "title": "Child 2",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": "5eece36ee3a4f43ca8e9868c",
                        "title": "Child 3"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": "5eece9210a445e2d0ca78978",
                "title": "Temp"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I need to pull the `id` from each main object and child object. There can be any number of nested children; it can go down multiple levels so this needs to be able to adapt to however many children an object has. I tried mapping it and pulling the id to a new array but that only gives me the 2 main objects. Is there a way to do this where it creates an array with all `id`'s.

Something like this:

```
["5eece32be3a4f43ca8e98688", "5eece339e3a4f43ca8e98689", "5eece354e3a4f43ca8e9868a", "5eece362e3a4f43ca8e9868b", "5eece36ee3a4f43ca8e9868c", "5eece9210a445e2d0ca78978"]
```

Comment: That does not answer my question. That will only give me 2 id's, the 2 main parent objects. I need to go into each parent and get the children ids, and then the children id's inside those children and so on.

Comment: Ah! There's [an even better dupetarget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57342010/recursive-array-of-property-values-in-array-of-objects) for that. :-) Happy coding! *(Since you're new here, I'll just say: Duplicate questions are not **bad** questions. People tend to think they are, but every question that links to canonical answers improves the ways people can find the answers. Well,* nearly *every question...)*