# How to use recursive loop to get all the IDs?

Tags: javascript

```
   let detailsArray = [
        {
           "foldername":"myfolder",
           "files":[
              {
                 "fID":"55",
                 "name":"file51",
              },
           ],
           "files":[
              {
                 "foldername":"mySubFolder",
                 "forms":[
                    {
                       "fID":"1111",
                       "name":"file01",
                    },
                 ],
                 "folder":[
                    
                 ]
              },
              {
                "foldername":"mySubFolder02",
                "forms":[
                   {
                      "fID":"4444",
                      "name":"file02"
                   },
                ],
                "folder":[
                   
                ]
             },
           ],
        },
        {
            "foldername":"myfolder2",
            "files":[
               
            ],
            "files":[
               {
                  "foldername":"mySubFolder2",
                  "forms":[
                     {
                        "fID":"2222",
                        "name":"file03",
                     },
                  ],
                  "folder":[
                     
                  ]
               },
               {
                 "foldername":"mySubFolder03",
                 "forms":[
                    {
                       "fID":"3333",
                       "name":"file03"
                    },
                 ],
                 "folder":[
                    
                 ]
              },
            ],
         },
    ]
```

I wanted to get all the **fID** values which is in files arrays in above given array. Firstly I tried to get all the fIDs like this

```
let fids = [];
```

### 1st way

```
let folder= detailsArray .map(el => el.folder);
fids = folder.map(el => el.fID);
```

### 2nd way

```
detailsArray.forEach(el =>{

      if(el.folder.length > 0)
          allFormIds = el.folder.map(f => f.fID)

             
    
  })
```

Still I couldn't get correct way to do this. I wanted to use recursive loop for this question.

here is the expected output : **fids = [55,1111,4444,2222,3333]**

Comment: An object can't have multiple of the same key, there are 2 `files` keys

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recursive array of property values in array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57342010/recursive-array-of-property-values-in-array-of-objects)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With proper data format, you could take a recursive approach for getting nested objects/arrays.

```js
const
    flat = o => o && typeof o === 'object'
        ? 'fID' in o
            ? o.fID
            : Object.values(o).flatMap(flat)
        : [],
    data = [{ foldername: "myfolder", files: [{ fID: "55", name: "file51" }, { foldername: "mySubFolder", forms: [{ fID: "1111", name: "file01" }], folder: [] }, { foldername: "mySubFolder02", forms: [{ fID: "4444", name: "file02" }], folder: [] }] }, { foldername: "myfolder2", files: [{ foldername: "mySubFolder2", forms: [{ fID: "2222", name: "file03" }], folder: [] }, { foldername: "mySubFolder03", forms: [{ fID: "3333", name: "file03" }], folder: [] }] }],
    result = data.flatMap(flat);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like below:

```js
let detailsArray = [ { foldername: "myfolder", files: [], files: [ { foldername: "mySubFolder", forms: [ { fID: "1111", name: "file01", }, ], folder: [], }, { foldername: "mySubFolder02", forms: [ { fID: "4444", name: "file02", }, ], folder: [], }, ], }, { foldername: "myfolder2", files: [], files: [ { foldername: "mySubFolder2", forms: [ { fID: "2222", name: "file03", }, ], folder: [], }, { foldername: "mySubFolder03", forms: [ { fID: "3333", name: "file03", }, ], folder: [], }, ], }, ];

let output = detailsArray
  .flatMap(({ files }) => files)
  .flatMap(({ forms }) => forms.map(({ fID }) => fID))

console.log(output);
```

Using [Array.prototype.flatMap()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)

Comment: "55" is not in the output due to what @0stone0 mentioned in the comment

Comment: Thanks for this. I got the iedea

Answer (score 0):

As you asked for recursive solution, I think this solution should work for you.

```
function getIDs(values) {
  return values.reduce((acc, item) => {
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(item)) {
      if (key === "fID") {
        acc.push(value);
      }
      
      if (Array.isArray(value)) {
        const subvalues = getIDs(value);
        acc = acc.concat(subvalues);
      }
    }
    
    return acc;
  }, []);
}


console.log(getIDs(detailsArray))
```

Comment: Yes, here has things to learn thanks , only problem was it retrun multiple arrays instead of one, Thats ok, I just want to know the way to handle this , thanks

Comment: upvote it if you find this useful.

Comment: Sure I will, still not enough reputation for upveots .